# FabricJS lineHeight on iText styles array

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am banging my head against a wall with FabricJs. I am looking for a solution to be able to apply line height to to the styles array on iText; it just seems to ignore it completely.

So if I had 2 lines of text and wanted the first to be a line height of say 5:

"Test Line 1\n"
"Test Line 2\n"

I try the character array as the following which applies the font size to each character but completely ignores the line height:

```
0:{
    0:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    1:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    2:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    3:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    4:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    5:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    6:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    7:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    8:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    9:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    10:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    },
    11:{
        lineHeight:5,
        fontSize:10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [styles](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#styles) as object , where first level is line number, then  for character .

***DEMO***

```js
var text = "Test Line 1\nTest Line 2\n";

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  selection: false
});

var textObj = new fabric.Text(text, {
lineHeight:5,
  styles: {
    1: {
      0: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      1: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      2: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      3: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      4: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      5: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      6: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      7: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      8: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      9: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      10: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      11: {
        fontSize: 10
      }
    }
  }
});

canvas.add(textObj);
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width=500 height=400>
```

For V-1.7.5, `fabric.IText` contains styles property, its not there for `fabric.Text`

***DEMO***

```js
var text = "Test Line 1\nTest Line 2\n";

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  selection: false
});

var textObj = new fabric.IText(text, {
  lineHeight:5,
  styles: {
    1: {
      0: {
        fontSize: 5
      },
      1: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      2: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      3: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      4: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      5: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      6: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      7: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      8: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      9: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      10: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      11: {
        fontSize: 10
      }
    }
  }
});

canvas.add(textObj);
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.5/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width=500 height=400>
```

Comment: @GlenElkins Check the demo

Comment: What version of fabric is it? I’m currently using 1.7.5 I think , wondering if they fixed this in the later version. Only problem is with fabric 2 they changed things and now image clipTo doesn’t work the same

Comment: Yeh I’m using an extended itext and it doesn’t work with lineHeight in styles on 1.7.5 - it just ignores it but all other styles are applied. This could be in fact that the extended class is the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, I tested your sample code and as I thought, it doesn't work. I changed the lineHeight to 50 and it looks no different as if it were 5. In Safari and chrome

Comment: It seems as though it's fabric that's got a bug, if you loop over the characters and getCurrentCharStyle lineHeight is completely missing from the options

Comment: @GlenElkins lineHeight is a global property fro textobject, not for characters

Comment: Not when you override their functions , it still doesn't change the fact that it applies line height totally wrong